# How to display all the lables present on x and y axis in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

I have written following code as a practice exercise on matplotlib

```
   ax = f.gca()
   aa = ax.imshow(boston_corr,cmap = 'PiYG')
   x_label = [i for i in boston_df[:]]
   pd.Series(x_label)
   y_label = x_label.copy()
   ax.set_xticklabels(x_label,rotation=90)
   ax.set_yticklabels(y_label)
   plt.title('PCA component Matrix')
   cbar = plt.colorbar(aa,label = 'correlation value'
```

**Output of above code:**
[image]

Code contains 12 values on both axes but in the output only 6 are shown. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really a question of having matplotlib show every label.

Comment: Never set the xtickslabels without setting their positions. That is use `ax.set_xticks`. Consider reading https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Comment: oh, got it . Thanks for your response